# How to properly mock private members of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am trying to write some unit tests for a method that depends on another private method. - As shown in the example below:

```
def is_member_of(self, group_name):
  members = self.__get_group_members(group_name)
```

The private method that I'd like to mock is `__get_group_members`; I'd also like to mock the private attribute `__user_id` since it will be used in the `is_member_of` function (not shown in the example above).

What I have so far:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
  group_data = []
  user_id = 'test_user_id'

  def mock_dependencies(self, x):
    x.__user_id = mock.PropertyMock(return_value=self.user_id)
    x.__get_group_members = mock.MagicMock(return_value=self.group_data)

  def first_test(self):
    x = A(('name', 'group'))
    self.mock_dependencies(x)
    x.is_member_of('test_group')
```

When I invoke `x.is_member_of()` the mocking doesn't work as anticipated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can access a private attribute in Python since *private and protected are by convention.* - What you're looking for is basically using `_ClassName__private_attribute_name` since, python carries out the renaming in order to achieve the convention agreed upon.

**Example (returning a MagicMock):**

```
with mock.patch.object(Class, '_ClassName__private_attribute_name', return_value='value') as obj_mock:
    pass
```

**Example (returning a raw value):**

```
with mock.patch.object(Class, '_ClassName__private_attribute_name', new_callable=PropertyMock) as obj_mock:
    obj_mock.return_value = 'string value'
```

`Class` is a reference to the class itself - not the instance.

**Complete Example:**

```
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock
from unittest import TestCase, main


class Private:
    __attr = 'hello'


class PrivateTest(TestCase):
    @patch.object(Private, '_Private__attr', new_callable=PropertyMock)
    def test_private_attribute_value_change_decorator_success(self, private_mock):
        obj = Private()
        private_mock.return_value = 'string'

        self.assertEqual('string', obj._Private__attr)

    def test_private_attribute_value_change_context_manager_success(self):
        with patch.object(Private, '_Private__attr', new_callable=PropertyMock) as o_mock:
            obj = Private()

            o_mock.return_value = 'mocked value'
            self.assertEqual('mocked value', obj._Private__attr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Modifications to your example:**

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock, main


class A:
    __user_id = 3

    def __init__(self, user, group):
        """
        Your logic is missing - obviously
        :param user:
        :param group:
        """


    def __get_group_members(self):
        """
        Your logic is missing - obviously
        :return:
        """
        return ['user_1', 'user_2']

    def is_member_of(self, group_name):
        members = self.__get_group_members(group_name)

        # will return if the user is a member of the group
        return self.__user_id in members


class GroupTest(TestCase):
    group_data = [1, 2]
    user_id = 'test_user_id'

    @mock.patch.object(A, '_A__get_group_members')
    @mock.patch.object(A, '_A__user_id', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock)
    def test_this_is_my_first_success(self, user_id_mock: mock.PropertyMock, get_group_members_mock: mock.MagicMock):
        get_group_members_mock.return_value = self.group_data
        user_id_mock.return_value = 3

        x = A('user_3', 'this_group')
        self.assertEqual(False, x.is_member_of('test_group'))

    @mock.patch.object(A, '_A__get_group_members')
    @mock.patch.object(A, '_A__user_id', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock)
    def test_this_is_my_first_failure(self, user_id_mock: mock.PropertyMock, get_group_members_mock: mock.MagicMock):
        get_group_members_mock.return_value = self.group_data
        user_id_mock.return_value = 1

        x = A('user_1', 'this_group')
        self.assertEqual(True, x.is_member_of('test_group'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*If you know you'll mock these two attributes in all test cases you can add the decorators on the class level and expect the arguments like-wise.*

In the case where the *attribute is set through the `__init__` or any other method*, you could simply alter it as shown below.

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock, main


class A:
    def __init__(self, user, group):
        """
        Your logic is missing - obviously
        :param user:
        :param group:
        """


    def __get_group_members(self):
        """
        Your logic is missing - obviously
        :return:
        """
        return ['user_1', 'user_2']

    def is_member_of(self, group_name):
        members = self.__get_group_members(group_name)

        # will return if the user is a member of the group
        return self.__user_id in members


class GroupTest(TestCase):
    group_data = [1, 2]
    user_id = 'test_user_id'

    @mock.patch.object(A, '_A__get_group_members')
    def test_this_is_my_first_success(self, get_group_members_mock: mock.MagicMock):
        x = A('user_3', 'this_group')

        x._A__user_id = 5
        get_group_members_mock.return_value = self.group_data

        self.assertEqual(False, x.is_member_of('test_group'))

    @mock.patch.object(A, '_A__get_group_members')
    def test_this_is_my_first_failure(self, get_group_members_mock: mock.MagicMock):
        get_group_members_mock.return_value = self.group_data

        x = A('user_1', 'this_group')
        x._A__user_id = 1
        self.assertEqual(True, x.is_member_of('test_group'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: When trying to access the member, "obj.__private_attribute_name", gives `<MagicMock name='_ClassName__private_attribute_name' id='63191920'>` which is not what specified as the return value('value') for some reason. how can I fix this?

Comment: You're trying to use `PropertyMock` - Updated answer.

Comment: Got `<MagicMock name='_ClassName__private_attribute_name._Test__private_attribute_name' id='64741424'>' this time. Printing "obj_mock.__private_attribute_name" right after the return_value assignment

Comment: Let me check it for you one sec.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: It works fine for me; let me update the answer with another example.

Comment: That should do the job.

Comment: Tested both, but did not work. I guess something wrong with my setup as it works on your side...

Comment: If you're mocking `__get_group_members` why do you need to mock `__user_id` ?

Comment: Actually, `__user_id` is also used in `is_member_of` and obtained from some external service. Both `__user_id` and returning data from `__get_group_members` are needed for the subsequent process, which is omitted in the description above.

Comment: Ahh I see. - I think I understand what you're trying to do. - Let me modify the `__user_id` as well.

Comment: I just end up getting AttributeError: <class MyClass does not have the attribute 'MyClass__my_function'

Comment: Edit: Never mind. I eneded to put _MyClass__my_function. Missed the initial '_'.

Comment: I see that this works, but isn't it so that the solution relies upon python internal naming conventions which may be different from one python to another and maybe also differing between python versions?

Comment: @pqans I don't believe that this ever changed in regards to the naming convention of how protected/private etc work in Python. - I might be wrong.

Comment: then again, any major version can break compatibility and would require work to fix.

Comment: Generally I would be careful about relying on such expectations. However sometimes one needs a solution - NOW - and does not care about what happens some revisions after. This needs to be considered from case to case.

Comment: I don't agree, I don't think this is the case; what you're saying is equivalent to writing a for loop and wondering if the syntax will change. - It's a deeply implemented feature that might change in the future, anything can, but you need to be pragmatic.