# unable to mock all the private methods using python unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-s3

I have a core class where I am trying to read the zip file, unzip, get a specific file, and get the contents of that file. This works fine but now I am trying to mock all the things I used along the way.

```
class ZipService:
    def __init__(self, path: str):
        self.path = path
    def get_manifest_json_object(self):
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        bucket_name, key = self.__get_bucket_and_key()
        bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
        zip_object_reference = bucket.Object(key).get()["Body"]
        zip_object_bytes_stream = self.__get_zip_object_bytes_stream(zip_object_reference)
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_object_bytes_stream, mode='r')
        return self.__get_manifest_json(zipf)

    def __get_bucket_and_key(self):
        pattern = "https:\/\/(.?[^\.]*)\.(.?[^\/]*)\/(.*)"  # this regex is working but don't know how :D
        result = re.split(pattern, self.path)
        return result[1], result[3]

    def __get_zip_object_bytes_stream(self, zip_object_reference):
        return io.BytesIO(zip_object_reference.read())

    def __get_manifest_json(self, zipf):
        manifest_json_text = [zipf.read(name) for name in zipf.namelist() if "/manifest.json" in name][0].decode("utf-8")
        return json.loads(manifest_json_text)
```

For this I have written a test case that throws an error:

```
@patch('boto3.resource')
class TestZipService(TestCase):

    def test_zip_service(self, mock):
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        bucket = s3.Bucket("abc")
        bucket.Object.get.return_value = "some-value"
        zipfile.ZipFile.return_value = "/some-path"
        inst = ZipService("/some-path")
        with mock.patch.object(inst, "_ZipService__get_manifest_json", return_value={"a": "b"}) as some_object:
            expected = {"a": "b"}
            actual = inst.get_manifest_json_object()
            self.assertIsInstance(expected, actual)
```

**Error**:

```
bucket_name, key = self.__get_bucket_and_key()
  File "/Us.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/services/zip_service.py", line 29, in __get_bucket_and_key
    return result[1], result[3]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What exactly is wrong here? Any hints would also be appreciated. TIA

Comment: The path you give to your `ZipService` does not split in 4 parts with your regex. Voting to close as typo. For the rest, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55512826/17676984.

Comment: The duplicate question doesn't help me in any way. I am already mocking the private method.

Comment: Well, you aren't because it's executing the body of `__get_bucket_and_key`, which cannot split your input `path` with the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving your `ZipService` a path of `"/some-path"`.

Then you test its `get_manifest_json_object` method, whose 2nd statement calls `__get_bucket_and_key`.

You are not mocking `__get_bucket_and_key`, so when it's called it tries to process that input path with a regex split, which won't give you a collection with 4 items that it needs to `return result[1], result[3]`.

Hence, `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Either give your `ZipService` a proper path you'd expect, or mock all private methods used in `get_manifest_json_object`.

Comment: I will try it out and will share the results with you. Thanks for the hint though :)